# Copy implicit variables from an external defined file into a struct on IBM i

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a PF, referenced in an rpgle-program. The record format name is "ROETBL".

```
FROEPF     UF A E           K DISK
```

Now I create a struct of fields with a distinct name (C_ for "copy") from the resulting (internal) input specs:

```
DC_ROETBL       E DS                  EXTNAME(ROEPF:ROETBL) PREFIX(C_)
```

How am I supposed to to something like:

```
C                   MOVE      ROETBL        C_ROETBL
```

The compiler complains with RNF7260: ROETBL in Factor 2 isn't valid for the given operation.

Since I read that it's possible to utilize functions in the C library from within RPGLE, I also tried that to exploit using `memcpy`. Unfortunately, I don't have the exact error message at hand anymore but I also could not compile the source because ROETBL is not a pointer to a struct.

Any comments on that?  I am using operating system version V4R5.

Comment: This sounds like what EVAL-CORR was invented for, but you probably don't have that on your old OS version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike's right, EVAL-CORR is designed to make it easy to copy data from DS to DS...

But EVAL-CORR was added at v5r4...plus it's really designed for working with qualified data structures and doing I/O directly into a DS; as opposed to stand-a-lone global variables.

Your other issue is thinking that the format name (ROETBL) is a memory structure like a DS, it isn't.

Try defining another DS without a prefix, so that the file fields will be organized into a DS.

```
 fROEPF     UF A E           K DISK

 d rec           e ds                  extname(roepf)

 d rec2          e ds                  extname(roepf) prefix(c_)

 c                   eval      rec2 = rec
 c                   eval      *INLR = *ON
 c                   return
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that this kind of overlaying is possible. Does this create a true copy of the data in rec into rec2 or place only a reference (pointer) to rec into rec2?

Comment: @PoC Its a true copy...you aren't dealing with objects in RPG.